# Convert Days to Years as in following format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert 1701 days to 4.660 years...

I used this following query but i get only Year ....

My query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR , B.emp_join_date, GETDATE())  from employee B
```

Output I get:

```
4
```

Expected output:

```
4.660
```

How i get the result?

Comment: How many fractional years are in 1701 days depends on the exact time span in question, since not all years have the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use the approximation of 365.25 days per year:

```
select 1701 / 365.25
```

In your case, this would be:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, e.emp_join_date, GETDATE()) / 365.25
FROM employee e;
```

This actually returns 4.657.  If you want 4.660, can you explain how that is calculated?

Comment: OP seems to be dividing by 365 thus expecting 4.660.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, 1701 Days converted to years is 4.660274.

This code will produce the output:

```
DATEDIFF( DAY, e.emp_join_date, GETDATE() ) / 365.2524
```

If you want to omit the precision and show 4 instead of 4.660274, use the following code:

```
FLOOR( DATEDIFF(DAY, e.emp_join_date, GETDATE() ) / 365.2524 )
```

If you need to convert *total* days to years, months, and days (within in month), use the following code:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2019-01-10 00:00:00.000', GETDATE()) / 365.2524 AS 'Years'
DATEDIFF(DD, '2019-01-10 00:00:00.000', GETDATE()) / 30.4375 % 12 AS 'Months'
DATEDIFF(DD, '2019-01-10 00:00:00.000', GETDATE())  % 30.4375  AS 'Days'
```

The output in three separate columns is:

```
|Years |Months |Days |
|:-----|:------|:----|
|4     |7      |26   |
```

The following code "combines" the results into one column:

```
,CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, [cA].[Date2], GETDATE()) / 365.2524) AS varchar) + ' Years, ' + 
CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DD, [cA].[Date2], GETDATE()) / 30.4375) % 12 AS varchar) + ' Months ' + 
    CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DD, [cA].[Date2], GETDATE())  % 30.4375) AS varchar) + ' Days' AS 'Duration'
```

The output in one column is:

```
|Duration                      |
|:-----------------------------|
|4 Years, 7 Months, 26 Days   |
```

Note: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019. I kept the code very basic to facilitate the learning process. You could be more efficient by creating a FUNCTION. However, this depends on your rights to the database. I see a lot of people who are challenged due to having read-only access.

Hope this helps.  :-)